# Second question at top

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

Is there any way we can do or add the feature where we can **choose** what order our second (or more) answers appear in?

I recently posted a second answer to a question but was annoyed when it drifted to the top, as I felt my original answer was supreme with more detail and citations etc., so I would like it to be the first one viewed.

I'd like to request the feature of having a slider (or something of the like) where we can shift which order our other answers appear in.

Thanks.
--EDIT--

**Both answers are completely separate, it's just one is more likely to gain upvotes or an accept.**

Comment: This only applies where the same OP posts more than one answer on a question?

Comment: Currently, each user can decide, whether they want to sort the answers by their **activity** or **upvotes**. Hence, if one of your answers gains more upvotes, it will be shown on top anyway. Could you please specify, why the current way of sorting isn't satisfying?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should only ever be posting multiple answers if those answers are actually entirely independent of each other.  If you're posting an answer that relies on information posted in an earlier answer then *it shouldn't be a separate answer, it should be an edit to your earlier answer*.

If you simply felt that one answer is better than the other, and don't want people to see the worse answer then *don't post it in the first place*, since you apparently don't think it's useful.

Comment: See my edit for clarification

Comment: @Lordology As I already said in my answer, if you think one of your answers isn't a good answer then *don't post it*, or delete it, if it's already been posted.

Comment: Both are acceptable and good, though one is more likely to be better upvoted.

Comment: @Lordology Then why are you trying to actively prevent people from seeing it?  Why do you think it'll be useful for people to be seeing this solution that *you don't think is the best solution to the problem*?  For an answer to be a *good* answer it should be more than just "acceptable", it should be the best solution to that problem.

Comment: I'm not trying to *prevent people from seeing it*, I just want one behind the other.  Think of it this way:  If someone came and couldn't be bothered to look at *both* my answers, I'd want to ensure they saw my other one above it.

Comment: @Lordology So why do you think it's helpful to have a solution that you wouldn't actually recommend as the solution to the problem, and that you're worried about people reading it and implementing it when you think they shouldn't be?  If you want people to be reading the other answer instead then *don't give them the option of choosing wrong*, by only posting the good answer.

Comment: @Lordology you don't need two different answers to explain the same thing two different ways. If someone doesn't understand it the way you explained it, they will probably comment. That's exactly what comments are for: asking for or giving clarification.